# Why is user having same role/profile able to post in broadcast only Chatter group when others can not?

Tags: chatter, profile, role-hierarchy

I have created a private, broadcast Chatter group. I have a Visual Flow, triggered by a Process Builder process on a record change that will post a message to the Chatter group.

Based on user reports users are getting errors in the Visual Flow:

> Error Occurred: You don't have permission to do this.

So I gave the user executing the Flow access to the group with the Manager role, and the problem cleared up.

Here's where it gets strange. There's a user, let's just call her "Sally" sharing the same role and profile as the user I had to grant Manager access to in the Chatter group who is not only able to execute the Flow and post into the group, but she has full access to all group settings. She is not an admin, nor is she the group owner or even a member of the group.  Her manager (her superior role) is group owner, however.

Why is Sally able to change all group settings and post in the group when others sharing the same profile and role cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swisher,

**The reason for this, the user that triggers the process is not allowed to execute the action on the Process such as posting to a Private Chatter Group.**

To resolve this, make sure the user has access to the chatter group and allowed to create a Chatter Post by adding the user as a member of the Private Chatter Group or you can make the group Public.

For more info about the error your'e receiving please go the below article.
[Error 'You don't have permission to do this' in Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249154&type=1)

Can you check if there is a **permission set** assigned to Sally that gives her **Modify All Data** permission.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. However, my question was "Why is Sally able to change all group settings and post in the group when others sharing the same profile and role cannot?" I already identified the cause of the error.

Comment: Is there a chance of sally having a **permission** set assigned to her that is actually giving her more access than other user.

Comment: Can you look into this link regarding the permissions that can allow sally to configure group settings [What Your Chatter Group Role Allows You To Do](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_group_roles_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks, but like my question said, Sally isn't even a member of the groups she can post in, so she can't have any group role. She's has the same role and profile as other members who cannot post in the group unless they are added as group managers.

Comment: Sorry then. I will have to leave it to the rest of the community members.

Comment: Actually, your comment about Permission Sets was helpful. She is assigned `Modify All Data` permission, which I believe is the reason she can do this. If you modify our answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Great. Because the link i sent you earlier mentions Users with the **Modify All Data**  permission can perform all actions on all private and public groups, and users with the “View All Data” permission can view details of all private and public groups, regardless of membership. That's where i was curious to see if there is a permission set, i should have been more clear earlier. The above comment is locked for some reason, I'm unable to edit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78591/discussion-between-rajesh-varma-mudunuri-and-swisher-sweet).